# Java : How to draw graphic object?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am developing a small desktop application in Netbeans. The application is complete and working fine. A small description of application is as follow:

The application is basically an **object manager**, where user add new object, remove old objects and connect object with each other. What i did is that i simply add 3 panel and change its type to titled border. One for Add object one for remove and one for connect.

**Status:**

Every thing is working fine as expected.

**What Left:**

In order to make UI more appealing i added a new panel at the end and called it "Object Viewer". I am planing to visualize the steps which user performs e.g

1. If user add an object  then i that pannel i will daraw a little
   circle and fill it with green color
2. Similarly if user remove some object then again i will draw another
       cricle and fill that with red
3. And when user connects two object then i will draw two circle and
       connect them with a dotted line

This is my first java application, i only want to know how do i acheive this task. Some links or experience are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do that manually with [Java 2D](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp), which I don't recommend, or, since you are using Netbeans (and I assume the Netbeans Platform, but this is not required), I would strongly suggest looking at the [Netbeans Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/). It can do exactly what you want.

Comment: The [Java tutorials about graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) will give you more information on general graphic handling in Java.

Comment: @suknic - Doing graphs / connections / layouts in Java 2D is going to be such a lot of unnccesary work. The Netbeans Visual Library (which can be used without using the Netbeans Platform) does all of that for you.

Answer (score 2):

As for custom painting in swing, have a look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

However, I'd suggest using a graph visualization library like [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html) etc. Using this you'd basically only have to define your object graph.

Answer (score 1):

As Nico Huysamen said you can do that with Java 2D. But because it's your first Java application I strongly recommend to do it manually with this lybrary in order to understand how higer level lybraries work.